# How well does minion range scale on The Summoner?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I'm working on collecting a gear set for my summoner and I'm trying to figure out what stats to prioritize. I've heard range scales poorly but i haven't seen any solid numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that it doesn't scale very well. Having ~600 range will give you more than enough range, especially if they are under Buff Beams.

600 range will let you hit the upper floor dummy from just about anywhere in the tavern.